# Yii2 - Keep child data in select option from parent dependent dropdown in uclead Tabular Input

Tags: php, yii2

I made a tabular input where I would enter several records at once into one table in the database.
I use this extension: https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input/wiki/Usage#tabular-input
From this extension, I combine it with dependent dropdown.
Here is the code.

```
public function actionCreateMulti() {
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $models = [new MaterialLocations()];

    if ($request->isAjax) {
        /**
         *   Process for ajax request
         */
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if ($request->isGet) {
            return [
                'title' => "Create new MaterialLocations",
                'content' => $this->renderAjax('_form_create_multi', [
                    'models' => $models,
                ]),
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Order', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
            ];

        } else if ($eglData = $request->post('MaterialLocations', [])) {

            foreach (array_keys($eglData) as $index) {
                $models[$index] = new MaterialLocations();
            }

            if (Model::loadMultiple($models, $request->post()) && ActiveForm::validateMultiple($models)) { // if failed
                 return [
                     'title' => "Create new MaterialLocations",
                     'content' => $this->renderAjax('_form_create_multi', [
                         'models' => $models,
                     ]),
                     'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                         Html::button('Order', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
                 ];

            } else { // success

                foreach ($models as $single) {
                    $single->save(false);
                }
                return [
                    'forceReload' => '#crud-datatable-pjax',
                    'title' => "Create new MaterialLocations",
                    'content' => '<span class="text-success">Create MaterialLocations success</span>',
                    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                        Html::a('Create More', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'role' => 'modal-remote'])
                ];
            }
        } else {
            return [
                'title' => "Create new MaterialLocations",
                'content' => '<pre>' . VarDumper::dumpAsString($request->post()) . '</pre>',
                'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default pull-left', 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) .
                    Html::button('Order', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'type' => "submit"])
            ];
        }
    } else {
        /**
         *   Process for non-ajax request
         */
        new ForbiddenHttpException(); // just for test
    }
}
```

And the following is a view of the tabular input.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?php try {
    echo TabularInput::widget([
        'id' => 'some-id',
        'models' => $models,
        'cloneButton' => true,
        'addButtonPosition' => MultipleInput::POS_FOOTER,
        'sortable' => true,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'name' => 'cupboard_id',
                'title' => $models[0]->getAttributeLabel('cupboard_id'),
                'enableError' => true,
                'type' => Select2::className(),
                'options' => [
                    'data' => $cupBoards,
                    'options' => [
                        'prompt' => '== Choose a vendor ==',
                        'onChange' => $jsOnChange, // this is handle onChange to find list row
                        'class' => 'form-control cupboard-id',
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'row',
                'title' => $models[0]->getAttributeLabel('row'),
                'type' => 'dropDownList',
                'items' => [],
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return $data->row;
                },
                'options' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control row-cupboard',
                ],
                'columnOptions' => [
                    'style' => 'width: 100px;',
                ]

            ],
        ],
    ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

As you can see, the first input column is: 'cupboard_id',
If there is onChange, it will generate data for the 'row' column.

```
<?php
    $urlOnChangeCupboard = Url::toRoute(['cupboards/find-row-column-available']);
    $jsOnChange = <<<JS
        var cupboard = jQuery(this);
        var row = cupboard.closest('tr');
        var rowCupboard = row.find('.row-cupboard');
        var columnCupboard = row.find('.column-cupboard');

        jQuery.post('$urlOnChangeCupboard', { id : cupboard.val() }, function(response){
            rowCupboard.find('option').remove().end();
            columnCupboard.find('option').remove().end();

            jQuery.each(response.data.rows, function(index, value){
              rowCupboard.append('<option value=' + value + '>' + value + '</option>'); 
            });

        });

    JS;
?>

<?php
function callBack($cupboardID) {
    $data = Cupboards::find()->where(['id' => $cupboardID])->one();
    $rowsRaw = range($data->rows_start, $data->rows_amount);
    $rows = array_combine($rowsRaw, $rowsRaw);
    return $rows;
}
?>
```

The problem is, when POST (Submit) the data, and then it is validated and there are still errors,
data from the column row should still be based on the cupboard selection.

At this time, after posting, the data from 'row' is empty
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with columnOptions closure

```
[
    'name' => 'row',
    'title' => $models[0]->getAttributeLabel('row'),
    'type' => 'dropDownList',
    'items' => function ($model) {
        $data = [];
        if (isset($model->row)) {
            $cupBoards = Cupboards::find()->where(['id' => $model->cupboard_id])->one();
            $rowsRaw = range($cupBoards->rows_start, $cupBoards->rows_amount);
            $data = array_combine($rowsRaw, $rowsRaw);
        }
        return $data;
    },
    'value' => function ($data) {
        return $data->row;
    },
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-control row-cupboard',
    ],
    'columnOptions' => [
        'style' => 'width: 100px;',
    ]
],
```